# Shifting from json-server to any DB

Tags: reactjs, json, database

I was working on a project which uses json-server to fetch the data which is static and hardcoded but big enough to not simply store in the react app. Now I want to publish my react app but I have a strong feeling that it would not be able to fetch the data because of json-server.
How to move forward from this situation? Should I use any database like MongoDB to shift my json data?

Comment: if it's static data simply create a `json` file and import it.

Comment: it is a static file. what do you mean by importing it? I have created a json-file. But the thing is that I have to run `json-server --port (port no.) <file location>` in order to fetch the data from that file. When I publish it on lets say github will the fetch statement work?

Comment: I simply meant you create a static json file import in your component and use it.